# How do I get my image to fade in using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

Am new to coding and am (very) slowly trying my best to learn jQuery. After learning a few basic commands I thought I'd try and make an image slider from scratch, but I'm having trouble getting my first image to fadeIn.

Any help would be really appreciated.

**Here's the HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="slider">
        <img id="img1" src="img/img1.jpg" />
        <img id="img2" src="img/img2.jpg" />
        <img id="img3" src="img/img3.jpg" />
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="left">Previous</a>
    <a href="#" class="right">Next</a>
</div>
```

**Here's the CSS:**

```
#slider {
  width: 350px;
  height: 450px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Here's the jQuery:**

```
sliderInt=1;
sliderNext=2;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#slider > #img1").fadeIn(400);
});
```

edit: am also receiving this error message upon 'inspecting' too - Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: Is the images hidden at the beginning?

Comment: check your path to js file

Comment: Path to the js file is fine I think..

Comment: I've hidden all the images, and now they're not showing. But the first one still doesn't fade in for some reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>First: use either unique id or class instead of id. Ids must be unique.</del>

Secondly: hide `img` elements `display: none`

EDIT: sorry, sorry, ignore stuff about ids. you are all god ;)

EDIT: If you need help with arrows, here's a basic [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/battousa/bjzc61qc/1/) to get you started.

Comment: Hi, cheers for the help.

What do you mean by unique ID's - I thought mine already were?

Comment: I've hidden all the images, and now they're not showing. But the first one still doesn't fade in for some reason?

Comment: adjusted fiddle to use images here https://jsfiddle.net/battousa/bjzc61qc/2/  just doudle check with it

Comment: Cheers for the help, really appreciate it. One last q - in your example your img ID's are the same as mine (img1, img2 etc.) but in the jQuery you don't reference these image ID's, (all you put is 'img' not 'img1' how does this still work if you haven't directly referenced the image class?

Thanks a lot

Comment: no, I reference the same ids, just in different manner - `$('#img' + sliderInt). this jQuery selector consist of two parts: `#img` is static, but `sliderInt` is variable which is incremnted and later reset to 1. So you end up with selector  `#img1`, later  `#img2`, then  `#img3` and finaly  `#img1` again